# Как убрать искажения (муар) от освещения на поверхности из параллельных граней?

Tags: 3d, three.js

[image: Демонстрация искажений]

Думаю, что картинка хорошо иллюстрирует мой вопрос.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он явно не по теме

Comment: вопрос по теме, однако необходимо конкретизировать - какая техника освещения используется и как именно, привести код и еще наверное картинку без освещения. А так вообще неясно, что из этого является проблемами освещения, а что просто текстурой.

Comment: в three.js используется классическая shadow map

Comment: Вопрос вполне по теме, и деталей в первом приближении достаточно. Тип освещения тут не особо важен. Код тоже.По картинке видно, что ребра сделаны геометрией и проблема в частоколе светлых/темных ребер.

Answer (score 1):

Полностью - никак. Это одна из бед графики.

Причина в том, что с каждым последующим фрагментом, вам нужно усреднять значение для пикселя из всё большего количества контрастных текселей (или разно-ярких полигонов, в вашем случае).

Такой муар можно только уменьшать:

- используйте текстуру и анизотропную фильтрацию
- используйте суперсэмплинг и сглаживание
- используйте более ровную текстуру или освещение, чтобы не было таких контрастных переходов